# Outlook Rule for forwarding and bouncing?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, microsoft-outlook-2007, windows-live

In order to consolidate all my email, I wanted to forward all my Gmail(2 accounts) to a new Live(Hotmail) account.

I wanted all email arriving at my Gmail account to be forwarded to my Hotmail(easy enough) BUT I ALSO want all email arriving at Gmail to be replied back to sender with a message like: "Your email has been delivered BUT the user has moved onto xxxx@live.com . Please further all communication to this email".

Using Outlook as my email client, how can I work this out?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Gmail.com, go to Settings -> Tab 'General' -> 'Out of Office AutoReply' and set an auto-reply message.

[image]

Instead of using outlook to forward the mail, it could also be done in Gmail. This would mean that messages get forwarded instantaneously and not just when opening Outlook.

Go to Gmail.com, go to Settings -> Tab 'Forwarding and POP/IMAP' -> 'Forwarding' and set an e-mail address in 'Forward a copy of incoming mail to [MAIL ADDRESS] and [PROPER SETTING FOR YOU]'

[image]